# Full text of message in ActiveMQ log

Tags: log4j, activemq-classic

I get note in log:

`INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/10 18:57:49 |  INFO | Sending message: ActiveMQTextMessage {commandId = 5, responseRequired = false, messageId = ID:kataev-pc-44816-1415376508242-3:7:1:1:1, producerId = ID:kataev-pc-44816-1415376508242-3:7:1:1, destination = queue://foo.bar, ... , text = Enter some text here for the message body...E...sage body...}`

How can I change size of text field of message in the log for sent note? 
I searched it in log4j properties, activemq properties, no results.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean to truncate the message?

Comment: You'd need to look at whatever is producing the message.

Comment: @PaulVargas I want exactly the opposite, expand the message.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution? I'm trying to do get full text as well, but I can't  find how to do it from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the toString method of ActiveMQTextMessage is truncating the message text.
I cannot find a way to override this.